# Getting location in Android browser

Tags: android, html

The following code works on my desktop browser but not on my Android phone's default browser. I get an alert box for 'Browser support geolocation' but not an alert box for the location.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            alert('Browser support geolocation')
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else { alert('Browser does not support geolocation'); }

        function showPosition(position) {

            alert(position.coords.latitude + ":" + position.coords.longitude);
            document.title = position.coords.latitude + ":" + position.coords.longitude;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="coor">Loading...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: The above code ONLY works if I enabled the GPS on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me on the default browser (the two alerts).
You should check that the server that hosts the page is autorized by your phone and that access to location is also permited : look in the settings of your default browser.

Comment: I've enabled location sharing on my browser settings but still not working.